# How is CryptoNight variant 4 increasing the CPU to ASIC performance ratio?

Tags: cryptonight, proof-of-work, asic-development

At block 1788000, Monero will switch PoW from CryptoNight variant 2 to variant 4. This change has two main goals:

- break any current CNv2 ASIC
- make hypothetical CNv4 ASICs perform less well compared to CPUs, making designing such ASICs less appealing to a profit oriented outfit

How is that second goal technically achieved in practice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At block 1788000, Monero will switch PoW from CryptoNight variant 2 to variant 4

The current naming is a little misleading as we are really on variant 3 right now, with the next being variant 4. This is because variant 2 actually spanned 2 releases in quick succession. Naming aside...

> How is that second goal technically achieved in practice ?

The best answer is probably found in the [README](https://github.com/SChernykh/CryptonightR) from the original proposal. Quoting two pieces:

> It introduces random integer math into CryptonightV2 main loop.
>
> ...
>
> Instruction set is chosen from instructions that are
>   efficient on CPUs/GPUs compared to ASIC: all of them except XOR are
>   complex operations at logic circuit level and require O(logN) gate
>   delay. These operations have been studied extensively for decades and
>   modern CPUs/GPUs already have the best implementations.

Ultimately, the idea here (and in other similar proposals such as RandomX/RandomJS), is that the hashing function has to execute some random instructions (a program) which essentially means an ASIC/FPGA would need to have the properties of a CPU/GPU - being good at performing *general purpose* tasks. This defeats the whole purpose of an ASIC (application specific), therefore the idea is an ASIC can't be as good as general purpose hardware like CPUs/GPUs.

It will almost certainly obliterate any *current* ASICs/FPGAs, but worth noting a comment from hyc:

> CryptonightR is still only intended as a stop-gap. The instruction set it uses is small enough that a very simple CPU could be added to an ASIC to process it. There is no expectation for CN-R to have longer than 6 months effectiveness.

Comment: CryptonightR is still only intended as a stop-gap. The instruction set it uses is small enough that a very simple CPU could be added to an ASIC to process it. There is no expectation for CN-R to have longer than 6 months effectiveness.